# Using `setInterval` with Jest and async

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, jestjs, setinterval

I need to use Jest to test some TypeScript code containing a call to `setInterval`, containing an async call.
If I write some code like this:

```
export { }

let startTime: number;
let intervalTimer: NodeJS.Timer;

async function f2(): Promise<void> {
    console.log(Date.now() - startTime);
}

async function f1(): Promise<void> {
    intervalTimer = setInterval(async () => {
        console.log("Before", Date.now() - startTime);
        await f2();
        console.log("After", Date.now() - startTime);
    }, 200);
}

startTime = Date.now();
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(intervalTimer); }, 900);
f1();
```

When I run it, this is correctly printed to the console:

```
Before 201
202
After 202
Before 401
401
After 401
Before 602
602
After 602
Before 802
802
After 802
```

Though, if I run this Jest test:

```
let startTime: number;
let intervalTimer: NodeJS.Timer;

async function f2(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("f2", Date.now() - startTime);
}

async function f1(): Promise<void> {
    intervalTimer = setInterval(async () => {
        console.log("Before", Date.now() - startTime);
        await f2();
        console.log("After", Date.now() - startTime);
    }, 200);
}

describe('Suite1', () => {
    beforeEach(() => { jest.useFakeTimers(); });
    afterEach(() => { jest.useRealTimers(); });
    test('Case1', async () => {
        startTime = Date.now();
        setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(intervalTimer); }, 900);
        await f1();
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(900);
    });
});
```

This is printed:

```
Before 200
f2 200
Before 400
f2 400
Before 600
f2 600
Before 800
f2 800
After 900
After 900
After 900
After 900
```

How come the line printing "After" is run only at the end?
How can I have it run immediately after the call to `f2`?